# How to do Sorting and Indexing of data in between on Cloud Firestore?

Tags: database, sorting, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Task list Angular application. When I add data into my Firestore collection, i add them with creation date and time. So when i retrieve the records back i can easily order them by creation date.

This is fine so far. But i have to simulate something like a notepad application for Tasks.

If we enter 
Task1
Task2
Task3
Tesk4. So far its good.

But now if i want to Add Task5 between Task3 and 4, i am stuck. My Task5 always comes in the end. This is because i use creation datetime for sorting.

Please help me with a simple idea to be able to insert items in between the existing list and retrieve data accordingly.

I want the result to be like 
Task1
Task2
Task3
Task5
Task4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this;
increment for adding a doc to last,
decrement for adding a doc to first,
the average for adding a doc between the docs.

I mean,

```
Task1
  order:1
Task2
  order:2
Task3
  order:3
Task4
  order:4
```

```
Task1
  order:1
Task2
  order:2
Task3
  order:3
Task5
  order:3.5
Task4
  order:4
```

```
Task6
  order:0
Task1
  order:1
Task2
  order:2
Task3
  order:3
Task5
  order:3.5
Task4
  order:4
```